# Deleted iPhone 5 Storyboard retained

Tags: xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I need to add a storyboard to my app for the iPhone5 - as the autoLayout doesn't work for this project.

I created a storyboard from scratch and abandoned it (and deleted the file) when I realised I should have just copied and renamed the existing mainstoryboard file.

The problem is, that when I run the simulator as an iPhone 5, I still get the old deleted views. i have tried cleaning the project etc as suggested here in other posts. I have also checked to see if the old storyboard was saved anywhere silly - and it is not there.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned the project

Comment: Did you kill the app on your device/simulator?

Comment: I have just noticed - in the path for the file (which throws an exception coz it's not there!) - it says "/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-23-72/UITableView.m:5471" Not sure if this is relevant or not!

Comment: Yes, I have deleted the app from the Simulator

Comment: So it does throw the exception. What is it?

Comment: I've just gone through everything AGAIN... and it has worked this time - I must have done something out of sequence?! Thank you all for your help though!